# How to handle accounts with powershell?

Tags: user-accounts

Our company is changing everyone's AD user account from numeric to alpha or alphanumeric. The move-spuser command will not work because account 4510014 is now jasmith. 4510014 will fail because they are changing the account in AD. How do i do this change in SharePoint so user's permissions and mysite can reflect their new ID.

Comment: Have you looked at http://blogs.technet.com/b/sheyia/archive/2014/05/22/sharepoint-mysites-and-ad-domain-migrations-how-to-make-it-happen-smoothly.aspx

Comment: Thanks for sharing the article. I appreciate it. I will use migrate user instead of move-spuser. I will update this post with my test outcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work:

```
$user = Get-SPUser -Identity "i:0#.w|domain\4510014" -Web http://webUrl
Move-SPUser -Identity $user -NewAlias "domain\jasmith" -IgnoreSid
```

Note that `Move-SPUser` and `stsadm -o migrateuser` run the exact same function.

Comment: This works however in SP 2010 mysite url did not change the http://mysite.company.gv/person/4510014 to http://mysite.company.gv/person/jasmith. However it changed the url to new id (http://mysite.company.gv/personal/domain_jasmith). Is there any reason why 2010 would not change the url? Please suggest.

Comment: UPSA does have logic to change the URL when the sAMAccountName changes. My assumption is you have the option 'Domain and user name (will not have conflicts)' configured in Set up MySites in the UPSA.

Comment: both stsadm migrate user or move-spuser works in 2013 . but for some reason it does not change the url for the myside in 2010. myside setup looks right to me. any idea. is there additional user profile command i can run subsequently to change the mysite url

Comment: Change the format of the URL in Set Up MySites in the UPA. It will transition the sites URL gradually.

Comment: In SP2010 I have my site url just to be username (without domain). In UPS  "User name (resolve conflicts by using domain_username) Example: .../username/ or .../domain_username/" this option is checked.

Comment: And if you change that option to say "domain with username (no conflicts)", it will migrate the Site Collections to the new URL format.

Comment: But that option will use domain_username instead of username format. I guess I am okay with that. But it change existing users mysite path to domain_username or only for the one that I use move-spuser?

Comment: Trevor, I made the change you suggested in SharePoint 2010 and ran move-spuser. It did not change the url for the user's mysite.